# How can I optimize a Bond Portfolio in Practice?

Tags: fixed-income, bond

I'd like to optimize a bond portfolio with different bond classes (government bonds, corporates, ...) and different ratings as well as maturities. Is this even possible to optimize such a portfolio? And how should I do that in practice? Suggestions or recommendations for research or similar would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Optimization can be interpreted in different ways.  What are you optimizing for? Return, risk, drawdowns?

Comment: @Ralph Winters I`d like to optimize the return with constraints on e.g. duration

Comment: I would suggest not optimizing the portfolio in the "classical" sense (i.e. mean-variance). Conversely, your objective function should be something like the weighted OAS to Credit VaR ratio. In the CVaR calculation, you can take into account credit risk as well as the probability of migrating to worse rating notches (and default, of course).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mean variance optimizer such as [Portfolio Visualizer](https://www.portfoliovisualizer.com/optimize-portfolio) to include different bond assets with various durations and yields, and backtest the historical returns based upon risk tolerance and return. In your case, you might want to place constraints on the assets to reflect which ones you want to give higher or lower weights to.